# How to change scrollbar height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a block that has a property "overflow: scroll" I want to change the height of my scroll from https://ibb.co/gFyfDwT to this https://ibb.co/SsByRXB

**Lesson.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import less from "./css/lesson.module.css";
import "./css/betaLesson.css";

export class Lessons extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="abc">
                    <div className={less.wrapper}>
                        <div>
                            <div className={less.sidebar}>
                                <div>
                                    {listLessons}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

**style.css**

```
const sidebar: {
    width: 240px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: add styles to your question its incomplete

Answer (score 1):

You could add another class inside the div with all the lessons and than add a height inside depending on your requirements, which might be 300%.

```js
import React from 'react';
import less from "./css/lesson.module.css";
import "./css/betaLesson.css";

export class Lessons extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="abc">
                    <div className={less.wrapper}>
                        <div>
                            <div className={less.sidebar}>
                                <div className={less.lessons}>
                                    {listLessons}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

```css
const sidebar: {
    width: 240px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

const lessons: {
  height: 300% // or 2000px...
}
```